# React: Trying to choose which source of truth and state management solution is most efficient for this scenario

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend, react-state-management

I am trying to decide what state management solution to choose. I don't think I need Redux yet, maybe Context API or local storage can do the trick or maybe another proposition. All I simply need is for the states of my tabs to be directly connected to their directed URL upon clicking on them, AND for the state to persist upon refreshing the page. Of course, that means that as long as the URL has a certain string that the state will update to the related value of the Tab, that would also secure the state value when a link directing the user to that URL is clicked on.

I hope I was clear enough, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Here are the imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import {withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SearchBar from '../TopBar/SearchBar'
import Home from '../Screens/Home'
import Contact from '../Screens/Contact'
import Profile from '../Screens/Profile'
import Settings from '../Screens/Settings'
import Messages from '../Screens/Messages'
import Products from '../Screens/Products'
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
```

Drawer variable holding the tab structure:

```
const drawer = (
  <Route
    path="/"
    render={() => (
      <nav>
        <div style={{ left: 70, position: 'relative', marginTop: 40 }}>
          <VerticalTabs
            value={values}
            variant="fullWidth"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Capa_1"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  width="460.298px"
                  height="460.297px"
                  viewBox="0 0 460.298 460.297"
                  space="preserve"
                  fill={values === 0 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                  className="home"
                >
                  {homeA}
                  {homeB}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="home-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 0 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Home
                </p>
              }
            />
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/Screens/Contact"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  height="512pt"
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                  width="512pt"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill={values === 1 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                  className="processes"
                >
                  {ContactA}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="processes-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 1 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Contact
                </p>
              }
            />
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/Screens/Profile"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Capa_1"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 512.001 512.001"
                  space="preserve"
                  className="designs"
                  fill={values === 2 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                >
                  {ProfileA}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="designs-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 2 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Profile
                </p>
              }
            />
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/Screens/Settings"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Capa_1"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                  space="preserve"
                  className="materials"
                  fill={values === 3 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                >
                  {SettingsA}
                  {SettingsB}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="materials-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 3 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Settings
                </p>
              }
            />
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/Screens/Messages"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  width="512"
                  height="512"
                  viewBox="0 0 60 60"
                  version="1.1"
                  className="printers"
                  fill={values === 4 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                >
                  {MessagesA}
                  {MessagesB}
                  {MessagesC}
                  {MessagesD}
                  {MessagesE}
                  {MessagesF}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="printers-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 4 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Messages
                </p>
              }
            />
            <MyTab
              component={Link}
              to="/Screens/Products"
              disableRipple={widthS < 599 ? true : false}
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              icon={
                <svg
                  height="512pt"
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                  width="512pt"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="forum"
                  fill={values === 5 ? '#0D9DCE' : '#9B9B9B'}
                >
                  {ProductsA}
                  {ProductsB}
                  {ProductsC}
                </svg>
              }
              label={
                <p
                  className="QA-Text"
                  style={{ color: values === 5 ? 'white' : '#9B9B9B' }}
                >
                  Products
                </p>
              }
            />
          </VerticalTabs>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )}

/>
);
```

Here is the routing structure within BrowserRouter:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/Screens/Contact" component{Contact} />
  <Route path="/Screens/Profile" component={Profile} />
  <Route path="/Screens/Settings" component={Settings}  />
  <Route path="/Screens/Messages" component={Messages} />
  <Route path="/Screens/Products" component={Products}  />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: in other words, you need to switch between/initially open specific tab based on URL, right? it's called routing. the most popular router in react world is [`react-router`](https://glavcom.ua/interviews/surogatne-materinstvo-ukrajina-sered-svitovih-lideriv-515073.html)

Comment: I am using it already but for now, I just connected tabs to related components on Click. I don't think you get what I mean. I want to change the state based on the URL, if you think that react router v4 will help please show me a suggestion if you can. I believe that a componentWillMount() will be needed to in this case

Comment: I think he understands what you mean, if you want your tabs to depend on the url you have to switch the tabs from onclick to routed components. That's the most idiomatic way, you could peek into router state onMount but that should only be considered if you absolutely can't route them

Comment: Guys, the tab already links to the URL with the onClick prop, this is not what i am looking for. In this case, the tabs are connected to a State, when a tab is clicked upon the state changes ALREADY. But, when I refresh the page the state is initialized to 0 and what I would like is for it to stay at 2 for example when on a specific URL without need to CLICK on it. May it be writing the URL on the search, clicking on a link that redirects or Refreshing the page.

Comment: what I cannot get: "tab already links to the URL with the onClick" in meaning how this is related to `react-router`. I'm still thinking it's that you are looking for

Comment: I am already using React Router to direct the user to the concerned page (Components) onClick...    
          <Switch>
    
                  <Route path="/Screens/System" component={System} />
                  <Route path="/Screens/Messages" component={Messages} />
                  <Route path="/Screens/Materials" component={Materials}  />
                  <Route path="/Screens/Log" component={Log} />
                  <Route path="/Screens/Settings" component={Settings}  />
                  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
              
                </Switch>

Comment: so what stops you from using nested routes like `/Screens/Settings/Profile`, `/Screens/Settings/Contact`, `/Screens/Settings/Other Tab`?

Comment: you can serialize state(say form content) and put it into URL as well. router still may handle that

Comment: Hey @skyboyer could you write an example on your suggestion (demo if possible), i will check on it so if it works i will validate your answer thank you.

Comment: can you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with?

Comment: @skyboyer Sure I will re-edit my question with the code

Comment: so you are already using `react-router`. and you are asking for "All I simply need is for the states of my tabs to be directly connected to their directed URL upon clicking on them, AND for the state to persist upon refreshing the page". URL change/react-router already works this way. And you already have it. So what's wrong?

Comment: If it was I wouldn't be asking the question... Thanks for trying though